# brcc32 invalid bitmap format

Tags: delphi, icons, components, delphi-2010

i created a delphi component and i want to add an icon to it, i know the procedure to follow, but something does not work for me, so here is what I did:

- I Created a bitmap file.
- I Created an rc file (MyComponent.rc) using notepad and added this to it: TMyComponent BITMAP "MyComponent.bmp" , as my component name is:TMyComponent.
- I tried to get the res file using delphi ressource compiler : brcc32 Mycomponent.rc, but I'm getting error 1 33:invalid bitmap format.
  I tried to use the other alternative which is image editor, but there is no option to make a res file, may be I'm using the inappropriate software.
  Why do I get this error? or could you just give me a link to get the right image editor? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I always use the Emba Image Editor for this. That works fine for me. Create a component resource file, add your bitmaps, save as .dcr file, it's all good.

Comment: Is it intergrated in IDE or not? if not could you give me a link to download it? I can't find the soft after doing a search on google.

Comment: Installed into the bin directory, but perhaps not in recent versions. It may be that I am still using the Delphi 6 image editor!

Comment: Borland's Image Editor died a long time ago, it hasn't been distributed with the IDE for many years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `.bmp` file is 8-bit (256 colors) and is 24x24 pixels in size.

Also, the resource name needs to be the component class type in *all caps*:

```
TMYCOMPONENT BITMAP "MyComponent.bmp"
```

Also, the IDE supports 16x16, 24x24, and 32x32 component icons, so you should include 16x16 and 32x32 bitmaps in your resource as well (otherwise the IDE will resize the 24x24 bitmap when needed, which might not look good when shrunk/stretched):

```
TMYCOMPONENT BITMAP "MyComponent24x24.bmp"
TMYCOMPONENT16 BITMAP "MyComponent16x16.bmp"
TMYCOMPONENT32 BITMAP "MyComponent32x32.bmp"`
```

Comment: Yes, I had to check that the file is 8-bit, so I converted it to bitmap 256 colors using paint, happy to see my component with the icon.